# How to show the discontinuous function

Tags: fortran

I have to show a discontinuous function,but it shows

```
Error: Unclassifiable statement
```

I think I lost something but I don't know. Can anyone help me?

```
program hw1
real y
real x
if x=0.5 then abs(y)=0.5
x=0 then abs(y)>0.5 
x=1 then abs(y)<0.5
write(*,*) abs(y)
do y=-0.5,0.5,0.1
enddo
stop
end
```

Comment: Welcome, pleaase tak the [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 1):

Baically all your program is a mess of sometrhing that only superficially looks similar to Fortan. It is hard to pick the individual problems. All your programs should start with `implicit none`, it is very important.

Your syntax of the if conditional does not conform to the standard. You should consult basic Fortran tutorials and textbooks for the proper syntax

```
if (x==0.5) then
  abs(y)=0.5
else if (x==0) then
  abs(y)>0.5 
else if(x==1) then
  abs(y)<0.5
end if
```

But it is still nonsense you cannot assign to `abs(y)`. You did not even declare what `abs(y)` should be. Perhaps you want to assign to some variable?

The empty do loop is also completely wrong. You should make do loops with integer variables. If you want x to have values -0.5,0 and 0.5, you can use

```
do i = -1, 1
  x = 0.5 * i
end do
```

But these fixes only concern the syntactic problems. The code probaby will not solve your homework anyway, but you have to do some more own attempt yourself. We can only help with general problems, we cannot write your homework for you.